# Help writing test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller

I am trying to write a test class for my custom controller, but am only getting 30% coverage.

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class topRecordExt {

    public List<My_Lobby__c> getRecent2()
    {
        return [SELECT Id, Title__c, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate, VoteTotal__c
        FROM My_Lobby__c
        WHERE Active_Status__c = 'Active' 
        order by createdDate desc Limit 10];
    }
    public List<My_Lobby__c> getMostVoted2()
    {
        return [SELECT Id, Title__c, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate, VoteTotal__c 
        FROM My_Lobby__c
        WHERE Active_Status__c = 'Active' 
        order by VoteTotal__c desc, CreatedDate desc Limit 10];
    }
public List<AggregateResult> top6Contributors1
{
    get
    {
        if (top6Contributors1 == null)
        {
            top6Contributors1 = [
                SELECT CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name name,
                    count(Id) contributions
                FROM My_Lobby__c
                GROUP BY CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name
                ORDER BY count(CreatedById) desc limit 6
            ];
        }
        return top6Contributors1;
    }
    private set;
}

    public topRecordExt() {}
      // Code we will invoke on page load.
    public PageReference forwardToCustomAuthPage() {
        if(UserInfo.getUserType() == 'Guest'){
            return new PageReference('MyCenter/MyCenterLogin');
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Class so far:**

```
@isTest
private class TestTopRecords {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
         My_Lobby__c a = new Recent2(Title__c = 'Test', Active_Status__c = 'Active');
         insert a;

         My_Lobby__c c = new MostVoted2(Title__c = 'Test');
         insert c;

        My_Lobby__c d = new  top6Contributors1();
         return d;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get to 75%?

Comment: Not sure on how you are getting any coverage with that class. It should not even compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your extension and call actions on it. Considering your constructor does not take either `ApexPages.StandardController` or `ApexPages.StandardSetController`, this isn't really an extension, but a controller. Regardless, if you unit test your code it should look something like:

```
static testMethod void testGetRecent2()
{
    // set up some data
    topRecordExt extension = new topRecordExt();

    Test.startTest();
        extension.getRecent2();
    Test.stopTest();

    // make some assertions
}

static testMethod void testGetMostVoted2()
{
    // set up some data
    topRecordExt extension = new topRecordExt();

    Test.startTest();
        extension.getMostVoted2();
    Test.stopTest();

    // make some assertions
}
```

On a side note, you should really lazy load your queries:

```
public List<My_Lobby__c> recentLobbies
{
    get
    {
        if (recentLobbies == null)
        {
            recentLobies = [
                SELECT Id, Title__c, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate, VoteTotal__c
                FROM My_Lobby__c
                WHERE Active_Status__c = 'Active' 
                ORDER BY createdDate DESC
                LIMIT 10
            ];
        }
        return recentLobbies;
    }
    private set;
}
```